How can I get the TypeScript AST factory functions to set parents on nodes?
In this rather simple code, parent is undefined.
const test = ts.factory.createBinaryExpression(
  ts.factory.createPropertyAccessExpression(
    ts.factory.createIdentifier("state"),
    "Foo"
  ),
  ts.factory.createToken(ts.SyntaxKind.EqualsToken),
  ts.factory.createIdentifier("Bar")
);

console.log(
  "Parent of state identifier:",
  ts.SyntaxKind[test.left.expression.parent]
);

It seems that factory functions don't set the parents of nodes when they create them.
Is there a simple way to have them set? In fact, is there any way at all? node.parent = [whatever] is a TS error because parent is readonly.

There are 2 alternatives you can do to solve it.
The first is set the parents, for example code
// Create a source file to establish proper parent relationships
const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile(
    "test.ts",
    "",
    ts.ScriptTarget.Latest,
    /*setParentNodes*/ true
);

const test = ts.factory.createBinaryExpression(
    ts.factory.createPropertyAccessExpression(
        ts.factory.createIdentifier("state"),
        "Foo"
    ),
    ts.factory.createToken(ts.SyntaxKind.EqualsToken),
    ts.factory.createIdentifier("Bar")
);

// Set parent references
ts.setParents(test, sourceFile);

console.log(
    "Parent of state identifier:",
    ts.SyntaxKind[test.left.expression.parent.kind]
);

The second is using node factory context, for example code
const context = ts.factory.createParsingContext(ts.ScriptTarget.Latest);
const test = ts.factory.createBinaryExpression(
    ts.factory.createPropertyAccessExpression(
        ts.factory.createIdentifier("state"),
        "Foo",
        context
    ),
    ts.factory.createToken(ts.SyntaxKind.EqualsToken),
    ts.factory.createIdentifier("Bar"),
    context
);

// Now parent relationships should be established
console.log(
    "Parent of state identifier:",
    ts.SyntaxKind[test.left.expression.parent?.kind]
);


ts.setParents doesn't seem to exist on my typescript; I get a type error. I'm on ts 5.6.3 which is latest. Does it work for you? How did you get it to work? The second approach seems more promising, but how do you then insert that newly created node into part of the original AST and maintain parent relationships? (Sorry, I should have clarified in the original question that that was part of my issue.)

The way I got this to work was to manually update parent relationships throughout the entire AST:
  function updateParentReferences(node: ts.Node): void {
    ts.forEachChild(node, (child) => {
      (child as any).parent = node;
      updateParentReferences(child);
    });
  }

  updateParentReferences(rootAstNode)

I'm not sure if there's a better way; this seems hacky, but it does fix the issue.
